# How to call SOAP service from Spring Boot without marshalling and unmarshalling using JAXB?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, web-services, soap

I have a .jar package that I have generated from WSDL of the SOAP service war package. SOAP service doesn't have an equivalent JAXB-compatible package to use JAXB for marshalling and unmarshalling with WebServiceTemplate.

I am using the following code to call SOAP service with an equivalent JAXB package but right now I don't have JAXB equivalent SOAP service package to call in the SOAP client application then how to call SOAP service?

PersonActivityList.class

```
package com.test.jee.cxfws;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessorType.Field)
@XmlType(name = "personActivityList", proOrder = {"request"})

public class PersonActivityList{
    protected PersonActionRequest request;
    
    public PersonActivityList(){}
    
    public PersonActionRequest getRequest() {return this.request;}
    
    public void setRequest(PersonActionRequest var1) {this.request = var1;}
}
```

app.yml

```
personactivity:
uri: https:test.com/personactivity/V4
schema-path: "com.test.jee.cxfws"
wsdlVersion: 4.0
appId: pdv
```

PersonConfig.java

```
@Configuration
public class PersonConfig {

    @Value("${personactivity.uri}")
    String defaultUri;

    @Value("${personactivity.schema-path}")
    String schemaPath;

    // specifically the HTTP message sending functionality
    // sets up the HTTP client with appropriate connection settings, including timeouts and SSL/TLS configuration
    @Autowired
    TestConfig testConfig;

    // is an implementation of a client interceptor
    // this interceptor is responsible for adding custom headers to the outgoing requests in a web service client based on the values provided in the appId and userId properties.
    @Autowired
    TESTHeaderInterceptor headerInterceptor;

    Jaxb2Marshaller getJaxb2Marshaller() {
        Jaxb2Marshaller jaxb2Marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
        jaxb2Marshaller.setContextPath(schemaPath);
        return jaxb2Marshaller;
    }
    
    @Bean ("PersonWebServiceTemplate")
    public WebServiceTemplate updateWebServiceTemplate() throws Exception {
        SaajSoapMessageFactory messageFactory = new SaajSoapMessageFactory(MessageFactory.newInstance());
        messageFactory.afterPropertiesSet();
        WebServiceTemplate updateWebServiceTemplate = new WebServiceTemplate(messageFactory);
         updateWebServiceTemplate.setMarshaller(getJaxb2Marshaller());
        updateWebServiceTemplate.setUnmarshaller(getJaxb2Marshaller());
        updateWebServiceTemplate.setDefaultUri(defaultUri);
        updateWebServiceTemplate.setMessageSender(testConfig.createMessageSender());
        updateWebServiceTemplate.afterPropertiesSet();
        updateWebServiceTemplate.setInterceptors(new ClientInterceptor[]{headerInterceptor});
        return updateWebServiceTemplate;
    }

    public String getDefaultUri() {
        return defaultUri;
    }
}
```

PersonActivity.java

```
@Service
public class PublicActivity{
    @Autowired
    private WebServiceTemplate PersonWebServiceTemplate;
    
    public PersonActivityListResponse getPersonActivityList(PersonActivityList request) {
            PersonActivityListResponse response = (PersonActivityListResponse) PersonWebServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(request);
            return response;

    }
}
```

How to write the equivalent code to call SOAP service without using JAXB?

Comment: `@XmlType` is Jaxb, so why wouldn't it be possible to us JAXB as you already have it.

Comment: I'm getting javax.xml.bind.MarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[com.sun.istack.SAXException2: unable to marshal type "com.test.cxfws.PersonActivityList" as an element because it is missing an @XmlRootElement annotation].

Comment: You get this because there is no `@XmlRootElement` on your xml classes. If you used the proper plugins there will be an `ObjectFactory` which you can use to wrap your element into a `JaxbElement` (there is some `create*` method for that) you can use this to send your object. The same probably applies for the unmarshalling again.

Comment: May I know the plugin and some sample code on it?

Comment: You state you already generated the code, so why would you need an additional plugin? All the needed classes are already in the generated code.

Comment: I have below methods but I'm confused how to use these to wrap the element before sending to SOAP service. public PersonActivityList createPersonActivityList() {return new PersonActivityList();}
    @XmlElementDecl(
        namespace = "http://cxfws.jee.test.com/",
        name = “personActivityList"
    )
    public JAXBElement<PersonActivityList> createPersonActivityList(PersonActivityList var1) {
        return new JAXBElement(_PersonActivityList_QNAME, PersonActivityList.class, (Class)null, var1);
    }

Comment: I resolved using below code. 
public class PublicActivity{
    @Autowired
    private WebServiceTemplate PersonWebServiceTemplate;
    
    public PersonActivityListResponse getPersonActivityList(PersonActivityList request) {
  
JAXBElement< PersonActivityList > jaxbElement = new ObjectFactory().createPersonActivityList(request);
JAXBElement<PersonActivityListResponse> response =
        (JAXBElement<PersonActivityListResponse>) PersonServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(jaxbElement);
return response.getValue();


    }
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used below code and it worked.

```
@Service
public class PublicActivity {
    @Autowired
    private WebServiceTemplate PersonWebServiceTemplate;

    public PersonActivityListResponse getPersonActivityList(PersonActivityList request) {

        JAXBElement<PersonActivityList> jaxbElement = new ObjectFactory().createPersonActivityList(request);
        JAXBElement<PersonActivityListResponse> response =
                (JAXBElement<PersonActivityListResponse>) PersonServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(jaxbElement);
        return response.getValue();


    }
}
```